# Converting PDF to excel by using python, however, the excel file is empty?

Tags: python, excel, pdf, spyder

I'm a new python learner. Recently, I am trying to convert the pdf file to excel, however, the content of the output (excel file) is empty. The script can run successfully and I can get the excel file, but the content is gone. What mistake that I made? Thanks.

Input

```
import pdfplumber
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
path="C:/Users/home/Desktop/New folder/RN(G)_GazetteList.pdf.pdf"
pdf = pdfplumber.open(path)
print('\n')
print('start reading data')
print('\n')
ws.append(pdf.pages[0].extract_tables())
for page in pdf.pages:
    for table in page.extract_tables():
        for row in table:
            if "number" not in row:
                rowlist=str(row).replace("[","",).replace("]","").replace("'","").replace("\\n","").split(",")
                print(rowlist)
                ws.append(rowlist)
        print('---------- line ----------')
pdf.close()
wb.save('RN(G)_GazetteList.xlsx')
print('\n')
print('successful input excel')
print('saving place：')
print('RN(G)_GazetteList.xlsx')
print('\n')
```

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What does happen if you do `print(pdf.pages)` right after the `pdfplumber.open` line?

Comment: hello olinox14, thank you for your answer. I added `print(pdf.pages)`, however, the excel file still empty

Comment: Yeah, but does it print something in the console? can you see an output, like a list of page objects or something? What I would like to know for now is if pdf.pages yield any pages

Comment: The output just show the page number only, I think that the python cannot read my pdf because my pdf do not have any table inside?! My pdf only have a list of name and number...Also, there are 1098 pages in this pdf file. Thank you so much for your help.